# Working with Google Sheets API

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to work with Google Sheets API with Xamarin Forms but I'm facing with problems reading the client_secret.json file that is used to authenticate with Google as it does when programming with .NET. 
When executing the following lines:

```
using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        { ... }
```

I'm getting an error showing that can't find the file client_secret.json. I'm putting the property for that file in my solution making it to copy to directory with the "Always Copy" option, but no luck with this. (I'm using Visual Studio 2017).

Can anybody help me with this issue? Thank you.

Updated:
The code I use is the following (any help would be appreciated):

```
        AssetManager assets = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets;
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), @"client_secret.json");
        using (var asset = assets.Open("client_secret.json"))
        using (var dest = System.IO.File.Create(path))
            asset.CopyTo(dest);

        using (var stream = assets.Open(@"client_secret.json"))
        {
            var secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;

            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, "sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
         }
```

Comment: where did you use this code In Portable or In .Android project .. also did you resolve this issue

Comment: ..did you find a solution

Comment: I use a crossplatform .NET Standard app solution for use in Android and iOS platform.

Comment: could you please add more details and add an answer for this qusetion help me to avoid this issue .. thanks

Comment: can you please add more details

Comment: @MikeDarwish Sorry but I still haven't found a solution for this issue. It's so annoying

Comment: try to check my new answer, it is working fine for me using google api. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432846/how-to-read-data-from-google-spreadsheet-in-xamarin-forms/52556347#52556347

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with the client_secret.json file too. The instructions for where it belonged didn't work for me.

So I put a copy in my home directory's .credentials directory (/user/.credentials ), and I put a copy in the directory of the executing application - and one of the two worked. I would try placing client_secret.json in different directories until the application finds it.

Comment: could you please explain more .. what i need to do to avoid this issue

Comment: The app needs to be able to find it.  But perhaps in your case it's more than that.  Have you seen this page?  https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/using-credentials-between-your-server.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to do the following:

1-put the client_secret.json In **Assest**.

2-try to read the json from **Assest**

```
 using (var stream = this.Assets.Open(@"client_secret.json"))
    {
        var secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;
    }
```

Comment: Just add the json file in assest.  It will working fine .  But Google api doesn't support xamarin.android you will face another issue when you are trying to get authorization from Google.  I will paste the issue tomorrow morning

Comment: can you post your issue to know if it can help me?

Comment: yes .. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763914/get-google-credential-throws-unhandled-exception